# Tutorial for ethereum wallet creation in android

Tags: android, tutorials

I am very new to `ethereum` and would like to learn it. Is there some tutorial available which lets me create an `ethereum` wallet for android ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you just mean you'd like to create an address for receiving ether, then you can do that:

- [How to create an Ethereum address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7087/how-to-create-an-ethereum-address)
- [What is the recommended way to safely store Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether)

Specifically for Android:

[Are there any android wallets for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/835/are-there-any-android-wallets-for-ethereum?rq=1)

If by "wallet" you mean "smart contract", then yes, there are also tutorials available for learning how to write them:

[Ethereum Tutorial for Beginners](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/ethereum-tutorial-for-beginners?rq=1)

Comment: Probably a dupe of one of the questions I link to...