# Tutorials for creating ethereum wallet in android?

Tags: wallets, android

I saw a similarly named question [over here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/tutorial-for-ethereum-wallet-creation-in-android) but I sort of felt like it was closed by linking an irrelevant question which just lists existing ethereum wallets.

As I understand, I should have the ability to an create ethereum address and private key with it, suitable way to store it securely.
Ability to import an account in the wallet (i.e) given a private key, it should get the corresponding public key or use the underlying private key when given appropriate word phrases.

Then use the private keys to sign transactions for transfer.

So is there any tutorial that covers these? I understand I should use web3j for transactions but it requires some credentials to a wallet file, I'm not entirely sure how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you get the private key, you must encrypt it and save it on the App... on the client side...

Take a look on TrustWallet core, there are lots of sample how to generate an Wallet address, get the privatekey and the SeedPhrase!

I hope it help you!

Better late than never! haha