# Private Network Tutorial

Tags: private-blockchain

Can anyone point me to a good up-to-date tutorial on ethereum private networks?  The last one that I saw that was any good still refers to the "--genesis" flat (whereas now "init" is correct) and since I'm having trouble implementing my private network, I'd like to know for sure I have an up-to-date resource so I can debug better.

Thanks!

EDIT: I have been educated as to why this post isn't ideal for this forum.  My apologies.  Live and learn.

Comment: Hello stone.212, Your question will likely get flagged and closed because requests for tutorial links are considered off-topic here (this is probably why someone down voted your question already).  See this link for the reason behind this policy https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5952/ethereum-tutorial-for-beginners. Try asking on the https://forum.ethereum.org/ or on Reddit?  https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/61y5ix/welcome_to_rethereum_the_reddit_front_page_of_the/

Comment: Oh man, thank you.  I tried deleting this post but I cannot. So I'll look at the answers and try to mark one as correct quickly.

Comment: Funny, I wouldn't have asked for a book recommendation but I didn't think of this as being potentially flame-inducing... but now that I think of it I'm in total agreement.  So I officially apologize and appreciate the correction.

Comment: Stone.212, I think if you explained what specific problem(s) you are having with implementing your private network, and you clarified what you tried / what has not worked, your question would meet on topic guidelines, and you might get some good advice around how to troubleshoot that.  Maybe try to edit in that direction?

Comment: @Tesa Thank you.  I have a separate post that might help you understand the issue here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/geth-connecting-to-wrong-blockchain.  But I will still be looking for a tutorial on private blockchains, even when I get past that hurdle.

Answer (score 4):

the last up-to-date tutorial about how to build a private chain is on consensus blog check this link

https://media.consensys.net/how-to-build-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-fbf3904f337

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  I did not have success.  It doesn't explain how to build a private network so much as how to build a *specific* private network.

Comment: where do you stuck? it is well explained

Comment: I am not stuck.  That tutorial is for setting up a particular private network, not a tutorial for how to set up a private network in general.  I am grateful for the link but it doesn't help because it is for something different from what I'm doing.

Comment: Does this other post of mine help at all? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/geth-connecting-to-wrong-blockchain

Answer (score 2):

I shared the steps to setup private net in another question -

[How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network/16306#16306)

You can take a look.

Note: I'm assuming you have installed geth and go on your machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvote regardless.  I'll take a look soon.

Comment: I finally had time to go through that link.  Halfway through I realized it was the doc I originally used.  It doesn't help.  I follow the steps, geth starts, and... nothing.  "Nothing" means that my other two (parity) nodes do not notice a third node on the network.  This is the precise problem that leads me to ask for a private network tutorial.  Not a step by step necessarily but a tutorial.  Because I am guessing that I need to learn more in order to start debugging, since geth thinks everything is ok but it isn't.